# GitLab: Dynamically set tags for stage based on previous stages

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to set tags dynamically, based on results from previous stages?

We have an environment where DEMO/LIVE environments is mapped dynamically to one of two datacenters A/B. The mapping changes frequently. We want to use runners, tagged A and B respectively, and when running deploy_demo stage we want to dynamically choose A or B based on current system setup.

I managed to create a stage which determines which environment should be used A or B and exported this to environment variable. This variable however cannot be used in the 'tags'...

How to dynamically set the 'tags' so that correct runner will be chosen?

```
stages:
  - configure_demo_live
  - deploy_demo

configure_demo_live:
    stage: configure_demo_live
    tags:
      - dev
      - k8s
    image: alpine/helm:3.4.2
    script:
    - echo "SEL_DEMO=A" >> config.env
    artifacts:
      reports:
        dotenv: config.env

deploy_demo:
  image: alpine/helm:3.4.2
  script:
    - echo "Dummy work"
  stage: deploy_demo
  dependencies:
    - configure_demo_live
  environment:
    name: demo
  tags:
    - $SEL_DEMO
    - k8s
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to change the tags of the **runner** that is supposed to run


Suppose you have figured that the environment lives in datacenter **A**, therefore you should use runner **A**

In **configure_demo_live** job make a request to the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#update-runners-details


In order to add the tag **demo** to the appropriate runner

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners/<runner_id>" --form "tag_list=demo,k8s"
```

Now the runner A has the **demo** tag.

Now configure your gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy_demo:
  image: alpine/helm:3.4.2
  script:
    - echo "Dummy work"
  stage: deploy_demo
  dependencies:
    - configure_demo_live
  environment:
    name: demo
  tags:
    - demo
    - k8s

deploy_prod:
  image: alpine/helm:3.4.2
  script:
    - echo "Dummy work"
  stage: deploy_prod
  dependencies:
    - configure_demo_live
  environment:
    name: prod
  tags:
    - prod
    - k8s
```

With this architecture you have two jobs one for prod and one for demo. One executes to runner with tag **prod**, the other to runner with tag **demo**. But only one of this will be true, according to the results of **configure_demo_live** job. Since it will update the tags of the appropriate runner.

Make sure to add an **after_script** to reset the tags of the runner A in this example